# React hooks update query after mutation

Tags: reactjs, graphql

How to update my query after mutation. It should be updated without reloading

```
export const UPDATE_POST = gql`
    mutation updateUserTask($id: String!, $completed: Boolean!) {
        updatePost(nodeId: $id, completed: $completed) {
            post{
                id
                completed
            }
        }
    }
`;
const POST = gql`{.....}`
const [updatePost] = useMutation(UPDATE_PSP_TASK);
```

Comment: What does this have to do with `facebook-graph-api`? Please tag appropriately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this should do the trick:
`const [updatePost] = useMutation(UPDATE_PSP_TASK, POST)`